# Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

I have looked at other Questions of this type and none of them solved my problem. I am having this JavaScript code:

```
var count1;
for (count1 = 1; count1 < 11; count1++) {
  var article = res.articles[count1]
  var ImageURL = res.articles[count1].urlToImage
  $('#showNews').append('<div id="' + count1 + '" class="article"><div class="overlayart"><div class="art"><h3>' + article.title + '</h3 <p>' + article.description + '<br><br><button onclick="divLoad()">Follow Link</button></p></div></div></div>');
  $("#" + count1).css('background-image', 'url(' + ImageURL + ')');
  x = article.url;
}

function divLoad() {
  alert(article.url);
};
```

Basically there are 10 items with different articles. Scopes of variables are all correct. I can see the links of the items when I console log them in the loop. I want to alert each URL whenever each Item is clicked for a respected button. But when I click that I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: divLoad is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Am I missing something?

EDIT [My Full Code]:

```
var x;
function divLoad() {
alert(x);
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country='+country+'&apiKey=MYAPIKEY';
    $.getJSON(url).then(function(res){
        //console.log(res)
        var count1;
        for(count1 = 1; count1 < 11; count1++){
            var article = res.articles[count1]
            var ImageURL = res.articles[count1].urlToImage
            x = article.url;
            $('#showNews').append('<div id="'+count1+'" class="article"><div class="overlayart"><div class="art"><h3>'+article.title+'</h3><p>'+article.description+'<br><br><button onclick="divLoad()">Follow Link</button></p></div></div></div>');
            $("#"+count1).css('background-image','url(' + ImageURL + ')');

        }


    });
```

Comment: Is the code you posted wrapped up in another function, like a `window.onload` handler?

Comment: yes it is in wrapped inside the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... )`

Comment: well if the `divLoad` is inside of the document ready block, than it is not global.

Comment: Oh. I tried moving it to the top out of document ready. Now it alerts the url of the last item every time no matter what I click.

Comment: Well think about it.... You have multiple things calling the same function....

Comment: Change your var ImageURL on let ImageURL. And var count1 on let count1

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the full, updated code? I'm failing to see how `divLoad` (if moved out of the `document.ready` scope as you've said) is even able to access `article` at all.

Comment: You foor loop must look like this for **(let count1 = 1; count1 < 11; count1++) {}**. Delete **var count1;**

Comment: I edited with the full code. Please check. And I don't think `let count1` thing works.

Comment: @KumarPriyansh You're updating the same variable `x` with every iteration. Your function just alerts the current value of `x`. It will always just alert whatever `x` was set to last. You'll need to parameterize your function so it can reference a specific article.

Comment: @TylerRoper, what should I do to stop that iteration so that it loads different URLs? I am really not able to come up with a parameterized function. Can you show me how to do it? PS: I know what a parameterized function is, I don't know what to do in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're always referencing one single, global variable. That variable (`x`) will only ever hold the last value it was set to in your `for` loop.

Instead, we can append the articles and give each one a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) - that way, we can associate each element with a specific article URL.

```
function divLoad(url) {
  alert(url);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=' + "test" + '&apiKey=MYAPIKEY';
    $.getJSON(url).then(function(res) {
        for (let count1 = 1; count1 < 11; count1++) {
            let article = res.articles[count1];
            $('#showNews').append('<div id="' + count1 + '" class="article"><div class="overlayart"><div class="art"><h3>' + article.title + '</h3><p>' + article.description + '<br><br><button class="article-btn">Follow Link</button></p></div></div></div>');
            $("#" + count1)
              .css("background-image", "url('" + article.urlToImage + "'")
              .attr("data-url", article.url); //Associate the URL to the element
        }
    });

    $("#showNews").on("click", ".article-btn", function() {
        var url = $(this).closest(".article").attr("data-url"); //Get the associated URL
        divLoad(url);
    });
});
```

If you inspect the `<div class="article">` now, you'll see each one has a `data-url` attribute that holds its URL.